# Front end help needed

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Not sure if this is appropriate for SO, if not I will take down but I am in need of help doing some of my front-end. Basically I have a div and a child div that handles all my data that I need. that child div has a width, and it works well until you hit a certain point (if you minimize screen width you'll see what I am saying). How can I make it so the div holding the items is always centered? Also, I am asking in the sense of this being responsive.

Part 2) how can I make it so the button is always in the middle, but JUST to the right (because I plan on having a previous button)?

I am using twitter bootstrap if that helps with this! (I have tried a lot of things and have not had any success, I tried utilizing the 'pull-right' and 'pull-left' classes with no prevail, I have tried using the span classes they offer with no luck as well.)
 [Live demo](http://completesweets.azurewebsites.net/products)

code:

```
<h2 class="text-center">Our Products</h2>
                <form method="post">

                    <div class="container" style="width: 100%;">

                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="next"> Next </button>
                        <ul style="list-style-type: none; width: 70%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none; ">
                            @{
                                x = getPageNum * 6;
                            }
                            <div class="container" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; float: none; ">
                                @for (int i = x; i < @itemsPerPage; i++)
                                {
                                    <li style="display: inline-block;">
                                        <div class="container">

                                            <img src="~/Content/Images_fixed/@(Model[i].link).scale_20.jpg" width=" 190" height="130" />
                                            <p>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].title)
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].price)
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                }
                            </div>


                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see is that the Div containing the elements is centered in the middle, your problem is that the elements themselves are not centered inside that Div. What you can do is give the container That is holding both the pictures and the buttons Text-align: center;

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

that will center both the pictures and the button. Then give the button a little margin to move it to the right a little.

```
button {
    margin-left: 150px;
}
```